Having a BAD TIME with OAUTH PKCE - Spotify API - React/JavaScript
Good morning!
I am a new programmer going through an online bootcamp type course. Part of this course is to create a portfolio app using the Spotify API. In order to get my app to function, I have to use oAuth PKCE protocol and I am having a really hard time making a GET request with the token I get back. It LOOKS like I should have a good token, but when I make the request I get a 403 error back.
Much appreciate any help. Take it easy on me because I've only been programming for about 3 months, but any feedback about other parts of the app is appreciated.
import './App.css';
import SearchResults from './components/SearchResults';
import Playlist from './components/Playlist';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import styles from './css_modules/App.module.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SaveToSpotifyModal from './components/SaveToSpotifyModal';


function App() {
  const [userPlaylist, setUserPlaylist] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
  const [publicAccessToken, setPublicAccessToken] = useState(null);
  const [viewSaveToSpotify, setViewSaveToSpotify] = useState(false);
  const [playlistName, setPlaylistName] = useState('')

  // Search Handlers
  function handleSearchChange(e) {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }

  const clearSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearch('');
  };

  function handleSelect(track) {
    setUserPlaylist((prev) => [...prev, track]);
    console.log(userPlaylist); // To check what is added for debugging DELETE LATER
  }

  function handleRemove(indexToDelete) {
    setUserPlaylist((prevPlaylist) =>
      prevPlaylist.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
    );
  }
  
  //state and reactivity for Save Modal
  
  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    setViewSaveToSpotify(true)
  }
  const handleExitSaveModal = () => {
    setViewSaveToSpotify(false)
  }
  const handlePlaylistNameChange = e => {
    setPlaylistName(e.target.value)
  }
  async function getUserId() {
    const url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me';
    const token = localStorage.getItem('private_token'); // Ensure token exists
    console.log(`Token: ${token}`);
  
    if (!token) {
      console.error('No access token found.');
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` // Correct format
        },
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
      }
  
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json); // Log the user data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user data:', error.message);
    }
  }
  
  // Create Playlist
  async function createPlaylist(userId) {

  }


  // Save a playlist to spotify

  function postPlaylistToSpotify() {

  }

// PKCE OAuth Authorization Flow

async function userAuth() {
  // Save State 
  localStorage.setItem('userPlaylist', JSON.stringify(userPlaylist));
  localStorage.setItem('search', search);
  localStorage.setItem('tracks', JSON.stringify(tracks));
  localStorage.setItem('publicAccessToken', publicAccessToken);
  localStorage.setItem('viewSaveToSpotify', viewSaveToSpotify);
  localStorage.setItem('playlistName', playlistName);

  // Generate random string and code challenge for PKCE
  const generateRandomString = (length) => {
    const possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const values = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(length));
    return values.reduce((acc, x) => acc + possible[x % possible.length], "");
  }

  const codeVerifier = generateRandomString(64);
  console.log("Generated Code Verifier:", codeVerifier); // Debugging log

  const sha256 = async (plain) => {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = encoder.encode(plain);
    return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
  }

  const base64encode = (input) => {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(input)))
      .replace(/=/g, '')
      .replace(/\+/g, '-')
      .replace(/\//g, '_');
  }
 

   const hashed = await sha256(codeVerifier);
  
  

  const codeChallenge = base64encode(hashed);
  console.log("Generated Code Challenge:", codeChallenge); // Debugging

  const clientId = 'redacted';
  const redirectUri = `http://localhost:3000/`;
  const authUrl = new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize");

  // Store the code verifier to retrieve later when exchanging for access token
  localStorage.setItem('code_verifier', codeVerifier);
  console.log('Code Verifier Saved to localStorage:', codeVerifier); // Debugging

  const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private';
  

  const params = {
    response_type: 'code',
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: scope,
    code_challenge_method: 'S256',
    code_challenge: codeChallenge,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
  }

  // Redirect to Spotify's authorization page
  authUrl.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
  console.log('Redirecting to Spotify:', authUrl.toString()); // Debugging
  window.location.href = authUrl.toString(); // Redirects the user to the authorization URL
}


// Function to exchange the authorization code for an access token
async function getToken(code) {
  const clientId = 'redacted';
  const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  const codeVerifier = localStorage.getItem('code_verifier');

  const payload = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: clientId,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      code_verifier: codeVerifier,
    }),
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', payload);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Access Token Response:', data);
    localStorage.clear()
    localStorage.setItem('private_token', data.access_token); // Save token local
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching access token:', error);
  }
}

// useEffect to run after the user is redirected back with the authorization code

useEffect(() => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const code = urlParams.get('code'); // Get the authorization code from the URL

  // Only call getToken if there is a valid authorization code
  if (code) {
    console.log('Authorization Code Found:', code);
    getToken(code); // Exchange the code for an access token
  } else {
    console.log('No Authorization Code in URL.');
  }
}, []);

// Restore state after redirect
useEffect(() => {
  const savedUserPlaylist = localStorage.getItem('userPlaylist');
  const savedSearch = localStorage.getItem('search');
  const savedTracks = localStorage.getItem('tracks');
  const savedPublicAccessToken = localStorage.getItem('publicAccessToken');
  const savedViewSaveToSpotify = localStorage.getItem('viewSaveToSpotify');
  const savedPlaylistName = localStorage.getItem('playlistName');

  if (savedUserPlaylist) setUserPlaylist(JSON.parse(savedUserPlaylist));
  if (savedSearch) setSearch(savedSearch);
  if (savedTracks) setTracks(JSON.parse(savedTracks));
  if (savedPublicAccessToken) setPublicAccessToken(savedPublicAccessToken);
  if (savedViewSaveToSpotify) setViewSaveToSpotify(JSON.parse(savedViewSaveToSpotify));
  if (savedPlaylistName) setPlaylistName(savedPlaylistName);

  localStorage.removeItem('userPlaylist');
  localStorage.removeItem('search');
  localStorage.removeItem('tracks');
  localStorage.removeItem('publicAccessToken');
  localStorage.removeItem('viewSaveToSpotify');
  localStorage.removeItem('playlistName');
}, []);




  

  //generate publicAccessToken
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!publicAccessToken)
    getPublicAccessToken();
  }, []);

  // Function to fetch the access token using Client Credentials flow
  async function getPublicAccessToken() {
    const client_id = 'redacted'; // Replace with ID
    const client_secret = 'redacted'; // Replace with Secret

    const authOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret)}`, // Encode client_id:client_secret
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials' // Client Credentials flow
      }).toString()
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', authOptions);
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch access token');

      const data = await response.json();
      setPublicAccessToken(data.access_token); // Storetokken
      console.log('Access Token:', data.access_token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching access token:', error);
    }
  }

  // Function to search tracks using the public Spotify API
  async function searchTrack(query) {


    const baseUrl = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?limit=10&type=track&q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;

    try {
      const trackResults = await fetch(baseUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${publicAccessToken}` // Use the access token to authorize
        }
      });

      if (!trackResults.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Spotify API Error: ${trackResults.statusText}`);
      }

      const searchTracks = await trackResults.json();
      console.log('Search Results:', searchTracks);
      return searchTracks;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during search:', error);
    }
  }

  // Search submit fetches data
  async function handleSearchSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
  
    try {
      const searchResults = await searchTrack(search);
      console.log("Search Results:", searchResults); // Debugging log
  
      if (searchResults && searchResults.tracks && searchResults.tracks.items) {
        const extractedTracks = searchResults.tracks.items.map(track => ({
          id: track.id,
          trackName: track.name,
          artist: track.artists[0].name,
          imageUrl: track.album.images[0].url
        }));
        setTracks(extractedTracks); // Update tracks in state
      } else {
        console.error("No tracks found in search results.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching tracks:', error);
    }
  }
  


  return (
    <div className={styles.appWrapper}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <button onClick={getUserId}>Testy</button>
        <Hero
          clearSearch={clearSearch}
          handleSearchChange={handleSearchChange}
          handleSearchSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}
          search={search}
        />
        <SearchResults tracks={tracks} handleSelect={handleSelect} />
        <Playlist
          userPlaylist={userPlaylist}
          handleRemove={handleRemove}
          handleSaveClick={handleSaveClick}
        />
        <SaveToSpotifyModal 
          viewSaveToSpotify={viewSaveToSpotify}
          handleExitSaveModal={handleExitSaveModal}
          handlePlaylistNameChange={handlePlaylistNameChange}
          userAuth={userAuth}
          playlistName={playlistName}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I get a token back in the response from the code exchange that LOOKS like its giving me a good token with proper permissions.
I've tried copying this token and hard coding straight into my app in case I'm manipulating it wrong, but it still gives 403 error.
I authorized the user (me) in my app on the spotify dev page. Don't know where else to go?
VPN causing an issue? Something wrong with the async calls that is doing things out of order?
How I'm using local storage before/after redirect?

Update: My entire flow works on Safari but not on Chrome. Is this a CORS issue or some additional security imposed by Chrome?
